# Using CacheMode From Worker Thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I'm working with a WPF Canvas that contains a lot of elements. It needs to be able to pan and zoom. WPF cannot handle the layout of the canvas since it has too many elements (I don't know how many, but the XAML file is above 20mb).

The canvas is zoomed and panned using scale and translate transforms on the canvas' rendertransform.

A good trick I found is to use CacheMode. This fixes all panning problems as I generate a cache for the zoom level and set that. Easy, like this:

```
canvas.CacheMode = new BitmapCache(scale);
```

The problem is that I need to do it every time the scale changes (which is when the user zooms).

I understand that it will take some time to render the canvas and that is probably unavoidable. But how do I move that rendering to another thread so that it doesn't block the whole UI?

I understand the concept of Background Workers and Dispatcher and such, but I'm not sure how to handle this when the task that actually takes up all the time is the setting of a property that I can only access in the UI thread.

Is it possible to somehow generate the cache in another thread and then transfer it to the UI somehow?

Any other good ideas on how to lessen impact on the UI?

Comment: You need virtualization. There's no other way around this. And depending the amount of data you need to show, WPF might not be the best option and you might need `C++`, DirectX hardcore stuff. Anyways you can pretty much get away with it if you virtualize your UI, you need an `ItemsControl` and probably remove all that XAML hardcoded stuff and create a proper ViewModel or something, I don't know.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid virtualization by just doing the bitmap caching really. You're destroying my dreams ;-) And I cannot get away from WPF, since that's a requirement...

Comment: sure, WPF is awesome, but it suffers from a performance degradation caused by the constant "managed to native transition" in order to interact with the underlying native DirectX based libraries. This is why it does not perform well when drawing a large number of primitives such as lines or ellipses, etc.